# Resource value not showing in tooltip in Android Studio

Tags: macos, android-studio

I'm a new Mac user (coming from Windows). Still trying to get the hang of all the shortcuts for Android Studio.

On Windows, when completing a resource selection, the basic complete shortcut (ctrl+space) showed me a tooltip with all possible options. Sometimes it would also show a tooltip with the value for the resource, or if not, I could hit ctrl+q to bring that up.

Mac doesn't do that. The equivalent (F1) shows a tooltip with no documentation for the resource.

Is there any way I could adjust that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this table, you can find shortcuts for common operations:

[image]

to update your keymap in Mac OS X 10.5+ version keymaps go to:

- Preferences > Keymap.